# smack xmpp library Java

Tags: java, xmpp, chat, openfire, smack

I created a java project using the library smack. Also I created on my computer with a server xmpp openfire.
 
the address of my server is: 192.168.1.4
the port is: 5222

my problem is sending / reception of the messages. That is when I try to send a message to another user, the user does not receive it. now place my java program:

```
 ConnectionConfiguration config;
    XMPPConnection con;

    config = new ConnectionConfiguration("192.168.1.4", 5222);
    con = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);

    con.connect();

    /*This code is inside the button event log-in*/
    con.login(txtUsername.getText(), txtPassword.getText());


    /*this code is internal event of sending message to another user*/
    ChatManager chatmanager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(con);
    final Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat(txtDestUsers.getText(), new MessageListener() {

                        @Override
                           public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                              txtRicevuti.setText(message.getBody());
                           }
                        });

                        try {
                           newChat.sendMessage(txtMessage.getText());
                        }
                        catch (XMPPException | NotConnectedException e) {
                           System.out.println("Error Delivering block");
                        }

txtDestUsers =  contains the name of the recipient type B@192.168.1.4
txtMessage = message to be sent
txtUsername = myUsername (A@192.168.1.4)
txtPassword = myPassword
txtRicevuti = received messages
```

as a test I ran the program twice, and I logged in with the two accounts: A@192.168.1.4 and B@192.168.1.4

if I try to send a message to myself, the message arrives.
As if txtDestUsers insert the name of another user, the message does not arrive.

How so?

Answer (score -1):

```
Message message=new Message();
message.setTo(<JabberId>);
message.setType(Message.Type.chat);
message.setBody("Hello World!");

con.sendPacket(message);
```

This is how you send a message

```
PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
con.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
 public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
 Message message = (Message) packet;
 String body = message.getBody();
 String from = message.getFrom();
 }   
 }, filter);
```

Above snippet is how you receive a message.

For further reference please see this:
http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000119